# From array of objects to just array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query `db.collection('image').find({ category: "concept art"}, { projection: _id: 0, imgUrl:1 }).toArray()` and have an output:

```
[
    {
        "imgUrl": "images\\2020-01-23T14-41-48.158Z-abandoned.jpg"
    },
    {
        "imgUrl": "images\\2020-01-25T01-45-14.880Z-pIMG_6443.jpg"
    }
]
```

I want an output like this:

```
[
"images\\2020-01-23T14-41-48.158Z-abandoned.jpg",
  "images\\2020-01-25T01-45-14.880Z-pIMG_6443.jpg"
]
```

Where can I find some information about this or how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operator-reference) for that :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** match docs based on criteria same as find */
    { $match: { "category": "concept art" } },
    /** group all docs and push imageUrls to an array */
    { $group: { _id: '', imgUrl: { $push: '$imgUrl' } } },
    /** remove _id from final doc */
    { $project: { _id: 0 } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2bc27cdc95d08ab83819e8"),
    "category" : "concept art",
    "isImage" : true,
    "imgUrl" : "images\\2020-01-23T14-41-48.158Z-abandoned.jpg"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2bc27cdc95d08ab83819e9"),
    "category" : "concept art",
    "isImage" : true,
    "imgUrl" : "images\\2020-01-25T01-45-14.880Z-pIMG_6443.jpg"
}
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "imgUrl" : [ 
        "images\\2020-01-23T14-41-48.158Z-abandoned.jpg", 
        "images\\2020-01-25T01-45-14.880Z-pIMG_6443.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I got `[ { imgUrl: [ data ] } ]`. Can I get just `[ data ]`?

Comment: @nukuutos : It will return an array of objects or an object, So in your code you can do `dbResult.imgUrl`